# How to assert inside a pipeline in Elixir ExUnit.Case (Elixir)

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I have the following test that is working:

```
  test "accepts a request on a socket and sends back a response (using tasks)" do
    spawn(HttpServer, :start, [4000])

    urls = [
      "http://localhost:4000/products",
      "http://localhost:4000/shops",
    ]

    urls
    |> Enum.map(&Task.async(fn -> HTTPoison.get(&1) end))
    |> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
    |> Enum.map(&assert_successful_response/1)
  end

  defp assert_successful_response({:ok, response}) do
    assert response.status_code == 200
  end
```

However, I'm searching for a way to remove the `assert_successful_response` method and do the assertion inside the pipeline. The example below exemplify what I'm trying to accomplish, but of course, it isn't working:

```
    urls
    |> Enum.map(&Task.async(fn -> HTTPoison.get(&1) end))
    |> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
    |> Enum.map(&Task.async(fn(response) -> 
      assert response.status_code == 200
    end))
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, you don’t need `Enum.map/2` when you don’t use the result; use `Enum.each/2` instead.

If I understood the requirement properly, this would work:

```rb
urls
|> Enum.map(&Task.async(fn -> HTTPoison.get(&1) end))
|> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
|> Enum.each(&assert(match?({:ok, %{status_code: 200}}, &1)))
```

or, alternatively,

```rb
assert(elem(&1, 0) == :ok and elem(&1, 1).status_code == 200))
```